# weird ajax jquery problem

Tags: jquery, ajax

Hi when i send data like so:

```
    var deln =  jQuery(this).val();
$.post("index.php", { del: "John", deln : "" });
```

it does not work, but if i enter the deln var manually like:

```
var deln =  jQuery(this).val();
$.post("index.php", { del: "John", 8 : "" });
```

it does work... strange!! its only numbers that are returned if that helps....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just the way object literals work in JavaScript, you can't use a variable for the key, at least not with that notation.

You would need to construct the object using [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation) to have a dynamic key, like this:

```
var obj = { del: "John" };
obj[$(this).val()] = "";
$.post("index.php", obj);
```

---

Since you're passing an empty string through, why not reverse it?  Use a known key, like this:

```
$.post("index.php", { del: "John", id: $(this).val() });
```

Answer (score 0):

To dynamically set object property it is not possible to use variables as property names while using object notation construct ({} brackets).

To dynamically do this you can try the following:

```
var deln = jQuery(this).val();
var options = {}; // define object container

// now use object as an array
options["del"] = "John"; // this is same as: options.del = "John";
options[deln] = ""; // setting a property name by passing variable

// now simply pass in options object and thats it
$.post("index.php", options);
```

Since objects and arrays in javascript are similarly handeled (both can use [] brackets)

Comment: This is a little misleading, *anything* can use `[]`, it's bracket notation :)